# Wildfly 10 as load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, wildfly-10, wildfly-cluster

How can we use `wildfly10` as a load balance without `mod_proxy, mod_jk, mod_cluster`?

I have `20 servers` which are `standalone` and our requirement is to balance the load with `wildfly 10` only.

Answer (score 2):

Thsi is in the manual and accessible via a basic search:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Using+Wildfly+as+a+Load+Balancer?_sscc=t

Wildfly 10 adds support for using the Undertow subsystem as a load balancer. Wildfly supports two different approaches, you can either define a static load balancer, and specify the back end hosts in your configuration, or use it as a mod_cluster frontend, and use mod_cluster to dynamically update the hosts.

To use WildFly as a static load balancer the first step is to create a proxy handler in the Undertow subsystem. For the purposes of this example we are going to assume that our load balancer is going to load balance between two servers, sv1.foo.com and sv2.foo.com, and will be using the AJP protocol.

The first step is to add a reverse proxy handler to the Undertow subsystem:

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/reverse-proxy=my-handler:add()
```

Then we need to define outbound socket bindings for remote hosts

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=remote-host1/:add(host=sv1.foo.com, port=8009)
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=remote-host2/:add(host=sv2.foo.com, port=8009)
```

and than we add them as hosts to reverse proxy handler

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/reverse-proxy=my-handler/host=host1:add(outbound-socket-binding=remote-host1, scheme=ajp, instance-id=myroute, path=/test)
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/reverse-proxy=my-handler/host=host2:add(outbound-socket-binding=remote-host2, scheme=ajp, instance-id=myroute, path=/test)
```

Now we need to actually add the reverse proxy to a location. I am going to assume we are serving the path /app:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/location=\/app:add(handler=my-handler)
```

This is all there is to it. If you point your browser to http://localhost:8080/app you should be able to see the proxied content.